# Is saving the type in the base class considered bad programming

Tags: c++, derived-class

I want to know the type of my class at compilation and i want to know if my idea is considered bad programming or if its actually viable. May correct me if there is a better way to realize this.

```
class Base {
   int type = 0;
}

class Derivative : public Base{
   Derivative(){
      type = 1;
      SomeObject1 o;
      SomeAnotherObject o1;

   }
}

class Derivative2 : public Base{
   Derivative2(){
      type = 2;
      RandomObject test;
      AnotherObject v;
   }
}
```

Some method that gets `myBaseClass` as `Base`:

```
if(myBaseClass.type == 1){
   Derivative d = static_cast<Derivative>(myBaseClass);
   d.o;
   d.o1;
}

if(myBaseClass.type == 2){
   Derivative2 d = static_cast<Derivative2>(myBaseClass);
   d.test;
   d.v;
}
```

In my opinion it would be unusual to write virtual methods for all different Objects

Comment: How would you use `type`?

Comment: At least it is unusual. Most often you would use virtual functions to get different behavior for different derived classes.

Comment: ??? (Amongst other problems) Your example doesn't set the type variable until run-time, when the constructor is invoked. Compile-time is never going to happen with this system. There's already the `typeid` keyword for run-time determination. You'd be much better placed to ask about the problem you're trying to solve, rather than a particular approach to it. A classic case of X/Y problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @melpomene I edited it.

Comment: @CarmacMondra Why not just use `dynamic_cast`? (Or virtual functions.)

Comment: Yes, the idea of C++ is to get away from "type" fields at the start of data structures. Fall back to C if you find this is the way you want to go.

Comment: @melpomene `dynamic_cast` is considered bad practice imo. And wouldn´t it look bad if i declare functions for all objects in `Base`.

Comment: @CarmacMondra `dynamic_cast` is considered bad not because it's inherently wrong, but because it enables the kind of program you're trying to write here. In other words, what you're trying to do is "bad" (but it's hard to say without knowing more details and context), but `dynamic_cast` is the best way to implement it (certainly better than manually coded integer type fields).

Comment: @melpomene My `Derivative` Classes are added in a View and when I click on one of then a `mouseClicked` Method in Base gets called and with an observer it get this method where I want to use the Items of the `Derivatives`

Comment: Then read the bit about virtual functions in your c++ tutorial !

Answer (score 1):

> ## Is saving the type in the base class considered bad programming

## Definitely, yes!

Using a polymorphic virtual design you don't need to have that extra information stored into the base class. The compiler already does that for you:

```
class Base {
protected:
   virtual ~Base() {} // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
}; // Note the ;!

class Derivative : public Base{
};

class Derivative2 : public Base{
};
```

You can always detect the real class type from a `Base` pointer or reference with a `dynamic_cast` then:

```
Base* pd1 = new Derivative();
Base* pd2 = new Derivative2();

if(dynamic_cast<Derivative>(pd1)) { // Yields true
}
if(dynamic_cast<Derivative>(pd2)) { // Yields false
}
```

Though if you need to know that, that's a serious indicator of a bad design.

You should rather introduce some interfaces in form of pure virtual function definitions:

```
class Base {
protected:
   virtual ~Base() {}
public:
   virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Derivative : public Base{
public:
   void DoSomething() override {
       // provide an implementation specific for Derivative 
   }
};

class Derivative2 : public Base{
public:
   void DoSomething() override {
       // provide an implementation specific for Derivative2 
   }
};
```

That allows you to call `DoSomething()` without knowing the specific type that implements that function:

```
Base* pd1 = new Derivative();
Base* pd2 = new Derivative2();

pd1->DoSomething(); // calls Derivative specific implementation
pd2->DoSomething(); // calls Derivative2 specific implementation
```

---

To make safe and efficient use of the `static_cast` use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) instead:

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    void DoSomething() {
         static_cast<Derived*>(this)->DoSomething();
    }
};

class Derivative : public Base<Derivative> {
};

class Derivative2 : public Base<Derivative2> {
};
```

Comment: If i call `DoSomething` form another method in `Base` would it also call the implementation of the `Derivative` if it is one?

Comment: @CarmacMondra Yes. It will unless called from within the `Base` constructor body. That's the whole point of that feature. Closely related with the [Template Method Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method).

Comment: do i need to use CRTP?

Comment: @CarmacMondra No, you don't need to use it. Totally depends on your actual use case.

Comment: Whats the benefit of using it?

Comment: @CarmacMondra The benefit of CRTP is avoiding potentionally costly runtime mechanisms (like vtables and extra call dispatch mechanisms and such) in preference to have dispatching resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the (ugly) approach I used a few years back when hacking-together a pdf writer. It appears to solve exactly the same problem that you have.

```
pdfArray::pdfArray(const pdfArray &src)
{
    vecObjPtrIter iter;
    pdfObj *ptr;
    mArray = new vecObjPtr;

    for (iter=src.mArray->begin(); iter!=src.mArray->end(); iter++)
    {
        ptr = *iter;

        if (typeid(*ptr) == typeid(pdfString))
            addItem( (pdfString*)ptr );

        if (typeid(*ptr) == typeid(pdfInt))
            addItem( (pdfInt*)ptr );

        if (typeid(*ptr) == typeid(pdfFloat))
            addItem( (pdfFloat*)ptr );

        if (typeid(*ptr) == typeid(pdfArray))
            addItem( (pdfArray*)ptr );
    }
}
```

Comment: :red-faced: Yep, it's just a matter of replacing `addItem( (pdfArray*)ptr );` with `addItem( dynamic_cast<pdfArray*>ptr )` etc, isn't it? It would have been nicer if I'd better implemented the `addItem` member though.

Answer (score 0):

There are uses of this technique that are at least plausible.  One that I've seen involved a class hierarchy whose instances needed to be configured by the user (driven from Python) and then used in performance-critical code (in C++).  The base class provided a `getType()` method that returned an enumeration; the wrapper code in Python called this to discover which interface to offer the user.  Cross-language code often forces the use of simple-minded techniques like this based on agreed-upon integer labels.

More generally, sometimes good design principles like MVC encourage this sort of arrangement.  Even if the different layers are written in the same language, it's not necessarily a good idea for the underlying model objects to have methods like `makeQtWidgets()`, since it requires that layer to know not only about the GUI library but also about the layout and control flow of the user interface.

A practical point: to avoid the situation where a derived class fails to specify its type, the base class should require the value in its constructor:

```
struct Base {
  enum Type { derived1, derived2 };
  Base(Type t) : typ(t) { /* ... */ }
  virtual ~Base()=0;

  Type getType() const {return typ;}
  // ...

private:
  Type typ;
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
  Derived1() : Base(derived1) { /* ... */ }
  // ...
};
```

You might as well put the `enum` of all possibilities in the base class, since there must already be a central registry of the value for each derived class even if it's just on paper.  This is a downside beyond the several mentioned by others: this design requires that all the classes be centrally managed, with no possibility for independent extension.

Finally, despite that inflexibility the clients must always confront the ugly possibility of an object of an unexpected type:

```
void foo(const Base &b) {
  switch(b.getType()) {
  case Base::derived1: /* ... */ break;
  case Base::derived2: /* ... */ break;
  default:
    // what goes here?
  }
}
```